# Ionic tabs not showing

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs

On my homepage I have a set of tabs. When I click on the + icon, a new page (AddReportPage) is being pushed (this.navCtrl.push(AddReportPage)).

On this new page I want to display a new set of tabs with different icons and different functions(see image 2).

But when I use the ion-tabs, they're not being displayed...
These tabs have to execute functions with ionSelect.

Do you have a solution?

1.

[image: a]

2.

[image: b]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `tabsHideOnSubPages` property in your tab tag: [Ionic Docs - Tab](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tab/#output-events).

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab tabsHideOnSubPages="true" [root]="AddReportPage"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Then in your pushed page you'll be able to see the tabs from there.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working... There's an improvement, my tabs are there but they're not visible...

Comment: Can you share the lines of code involving the tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get pretty much the same result with an ion-toolbar in a ion-footer.
Thanks for the help!

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col no-padding>
          <button ion-button icon-only clear (click)="getPicture()">
            <ion-icon name="images"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col no-padding>
          <button ion-button icon-only clear (click)="takePicture()">
            <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col no-padding>
          <button ion-button icon-only clear>
            <ion-icon name="paper-plane"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```